# Having only one instance of the application at a time

Tags: java

My friend had the following question(s) asked in an interview :

1. How will you make sure that there is only one instance of an application(like tomcat) running at a time ?
2. When another instance of an application is started,an error message should be displayed saying one instance is already running
3. When the application has an abnormal termination, we should be able to start the application .

My answers to the above question involves ports. Does anyone has a "deeper" understanding of the above questions ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528844/only-one-swing-frame-window-opened-at-time/2528860#2528860

Comment: I would use a port as well.  Simple answers are often the best, so perhaps there isn't a deeper understanding.  The only trick I can think of is to use `socket.setReusableAddress(true)` **before** binding to the port. What is your doubt?

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend you to use "PID files".

You could for example create a PID file when you start your application (eg. under `/var/run/mypgm.pid`). In that pid file you store the PID (process-ID) of your application. When you shut down your application (clean) you remove that PID-file.

Now, when you start your application a 2nd time you check if that PID file exists. If the file exists you have two options:

- Your application is still running
- Your application crashed and the pid file is still there.

Now you can parse that PID file to check if there is still a process running with that PID. If so, you display your error message. If not, you just delete the PID-file and start your application.

Answer (score 1):

The [java.nio.channels.FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) can help you match all three points (including the abnormal termination case).

The example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DemonstratesfilelockingandsimplefilereadandwriteoperationsusingjavaniochannelsFileChannel.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possibilities to check for application already running scenario, i'm sure there are plenty more:

1. check that no other process with the same name is already running (problem if there IS an application with the same name, however unlikely)
2. use a file as a lock (but that might cause issues if you crash)

Displaying a message if an instance is already running is trivial once you've detected that it is running (just display the message and exit)

EDIT: @ortang using a PID file can still cause problems if another process received the same PID after your application crashed. In this case your application will not be able to start unless you delete the file manually.

Comment: You are right. You could narrow down the problem by: parsing the name of the program with that PID or use some kind of signal handler (eg. `trap` on EXIT) to remove the PID file, etc.